# Making EXE Installer from Netbeans9.0

Tags: java, exe, netbeans-9

I worked with that before in Netbeans 8.2, but in Apache Netbeans 9.0 it doesn't work and it display this when it finish:

> ant -f "C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre" -Djar.archive.disabled=true -Dnative.bundling.type=installer build-native
> Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.0
> Result: 1
> init:
> deps-clean:
> Updating property file: C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\build\built-clean.properties
> Deleting directory C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\build
> clean:
> deps-jar:
> Created dir: C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\build
> Updating property file: C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\build\built-jar.properties
> Created dir: C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\build\classes
> Created dir: C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\build\empty
> Created dir: C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
> Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\build\classes
> compile:
> Created dir: C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\dist
> Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
> Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
> C:\Users\So Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\semestre\nbproject\build-native.xml:519: typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found
>  using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)

I know how can I do it from [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html)

Comment: I see a bug that was logged and closed by the person that logged it : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8119751
Maybe you also have unresolved dependencies ?

Comment: yes, I see this page but it doesn't help.